# if f(n) = n-100 and g(n) = n-200 is f equal to big o of g or omega of g or theta of g

Tags: algorithm

hi guys im self studying algorithms using Mr. Dasguptas book. I cant seem to find the solution manual so thought of posting my questions here. any ways the problem is as the title states if

if f(n) = n-100 and g(n) = n-200 
is f equal to big o of  g or omega of g or theta of g
i think its theta of g but not sure

Comment: simply use the definitions of O, Omega and Theta

Comment: IMO, f(n) is not equal to Big anything. That is most misleading, inconsistent and nonsensical notation you can use. How can a function be equal to a class of functions? Also there is plenty resources how to obtain those notations and how to use them. Show some effort.

Comment: well as far as i understand for O there must be a constant c that f(n) <cg(n)and for omega f(n)>cg(n) thus for omega c can be one (given n is positive). what im not sure is whether there is a constant c where f(n)<cg(n).

Comment: I think this is only "half" of the definition.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about asymptotic behaviour and belongs to [Computer Science SX](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: well according to the algorithms book by Mr Dasgupta here is the definition Let f(n) and g(n) be functions from positive integers to positive reals. We say
f = O(g) (which means that f grows no faster than g) if there is a constant c > 0
such that f(n)  <= c  g(n).

Comment: hi sorry for posting the question on the wrong forum. Is there a way to moove this question to the above mentioned 
Computer Science one

Answer (score 2):

Neither - O(g) is a set of functions and a function can not be equal to set of fucntions right?

- O(g) - the functions that are growing at MOST as fast as function `g`
- Ω(g) - the functions that are growing at LEAST as fast as function `g`
- Θ(g) - the functions that are growing at EXACTLY as fast as function `g`

You should use rather the term `belongs`, or `is member of` in the case of set association.

The most correct thing to say is that f is member of Θ(g) denoted by f ∈ Θ(g). F really grows exactly as fast as g.

Comment: according the book it says to say f ∈ Θ(g) one must prove   f ∈ O(g) as well as f ∈ Ω(g).definition says for f ∈ O(g) there must be a constant c>0 such that f<=c.g(n). Im having trouble finding this constant

Comment: @user119020 I do not know which exactly book you are speaking about, but the definition you cite is not 100% accurate. Usually this is defined with limeses for n approaching infinity. With your definition any constant greater than one would suffice with big enough values of n.